# User creation from request POST through crul/http.

Tags: django, curl, passwords, token

I am trying to create users from a POST request sent from curl/httpie commands. Users are created in the User Model, but the password is stored in raw string format. This is what i do.

```html
http POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/ username=taco password=123
```

This creates a User with the following credentials.

Now when I enter my admin site, and click on the details of user created. The password shows like this.

```html
Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm.
Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this user's password, but you can change the password using this form.
```

I have automatic token creation system on user post_save. Token is also created. but when i put.

```html
http POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/obtain/ username=taco password=123
```

url***/obtain goes to views.obtain_auth_token imported from rest_framework.authtoken.views from which I receive the token for the specified User.

but I get a error saying..

```html
"non_field_errors": [
        "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
]
```

I basically want to signup(create) a user from terminal(http/curl) and obtain their token from "/obtain"

Answer (score 0):

No worries It so happened that you cant post password in raw string. 
so by capturing the .username and .password from the query paramenter. I wrote a a create user code on my view , and set the password using .setpassword().